# How to get the position of the clicking Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the position of clicked element position. If i clicked First p tag, the alert box have to give output 1. if i clicked some text p tag then it should give output 3. I don't know how to do it. Please anyone give me solution. Thanks in advance.

Below is my HTML code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>First</p>
    <p>Second</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Below is my JQuery code

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $('p').click(function() {
    alert("You clicked nth position tag");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**.index()**](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
$('p').on('click', function() {
  //add 1 to get the desired result 
  //because index starts from 0 
  console.log($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

For your new requirement you can use [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```js
$('p').on('click', function() {
  console.log(`You clicked ${$(this).index() + 1} nth position tag with text: ${$(this).text()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

I used [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but you can simple use string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks alex. Is there any option to get tag text by using index

Comment: Hi alex can you join this chat room. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120404/room-for-kaja-mydeen-and-alex-char

Answer (score 1):

> alert("You clicked " + ($(this).index() + 1) + " position tag");